# VBA (highlight Hardcode cell (i.e.1234) in Excel) after model is built

Tags: vba, excel, highlighting

I'm building a financial model and i'm trying to highlight all the cells after the model is complete. I need to identify which one are hardcoded after the model is completely without searching for each input one by one.

it would be great, If you can help with a vba for the whole excel tab and a selected range on a sheet. thank you.

Comment: Try hitting `Control~` ? I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are asking is to look through a range, and then highlight any values within that range that don't contain a formula. So first find the range you want to highlight and then find the ranges within that range that contain a formula. For my example we'll say that your model is from cells A1 to A100

```
Public Sub hightlightNoFormulas()
     Dim yourRange as Range, rangeNoFormula as Range
     Set yourRange = Range("A1:A100")
     Set rangeNoFormula = yourRange.SpecialCells xlCellTypeFormulas
```

Then loop through your range, excluding any values that have formulas

```
     Dim rng as Range
     For Each rng in yourRange
          If Intersect(rng,rangeNoFormula) Is Nothing Then
               rng.interior.Color = 65535
          End If
     Next rng
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was looking for ranges that doesn't contain any formula!. Thanks