# Highlight cells in a range that are "hard-coded" and not formula derived

Tags: vba, excel, highlighting

I found this code on Stackoverflow [VBA (highlight Hardcode cell (i.e.1234) in Excel) after model is built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388721/vba-highlight-hardcode-cell-i-e-1234-in-excel-after-model-is-built)

```
 Public Sub hightlightNoFormulas()
    Dim yourRange as Range, rangeNoFormula as Range
    Set yourRange = Range("A1:A100")
    Set rangeNoFormula = yourRange.SpecialCells xlCellTypeFormulas

Then loop through your range, excluding any values that have formulas  

    Dim rng as Range
       For Each rng in yourRange
          If Intersect(rng,rangeNoFormula) Is Nothing Then
               rng.interior.Color = 65535
          End If
       Next rng
    Exit Sub
```

Although the **`"Set rangeNoFormula = yourRange.SpecialCells xlCellTypeFormulas"`** section errors out in Excel 2010.  I have been looking for code that highlights cells in a selectable range that are "hard-coded" and not formula derived (i.e where cell formula was over-typed).  Can someone please provide help?  Thanks.

Comment: If you change  ~ xlCellTypeFormulas~   To    ~ xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions.~  or ~xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions.~ does it help you.

Comment: take a look at the first response if you google vba specialcells and it will show you that the syntax is wrong. `yourrange.specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended modifying this code and adding a an input box to select the range I want to inspect. The code works great for my needs.  Thanks everyone!

```
    Public Sub hightlightNoFormulas()
    Dim yourRange As Range, rangeNoFormula As Range

 On Error GoTo GetOut        'if no hard coded cells are found in the range, go to "GetOut" to exit Sub

    'Set Range as popup input box.
 Set yourRange = Application.InputBox( _
 Prompt:="Select a range.", _
 Title:="INPUT RANGE", _
 Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)

    'Type: Value Meaning
    '0  A Formula
    '1  A Number
    '2 Text (a string)
    '4 A logical value (True or False)
    '8 A cell reference, as a Range object
    '16 An error value, such as #N/A
    '64 An array of values

    On Error GoTo GetOut        'if no hard coded cells are found in the range, go to "GetOut" to exit Sub

    Set rangeNoFormula = yourRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)      'identifies cells without formulas
    rangeNoFormula.Interior.Color = 42495

GetOut:     'exits the sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop..............just color constants:

```
Public Sub hightlightNoFormulas()
    Dim yourRange As Range, rangeNoFormula As Range
    Set yourRange = Range("A1:A100")
    Set rangeNoFormula = yourRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rangeNoFormula.Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```

Comment: Simpler yet,  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ranges have a built-in Boolean function called `HasFormula()` that you can use.
Your code would look like this (I cleaned it up a tiny bit too):

```
Public Sub hightlightNoFormulas()
Dim yourRange as Range, rng as Range
   Set yourRange = Range("A1:A100")

   For Each rng in yourRange
      If Not rng.HasFormula Then
           rng.interior.Color = 65535
      End If
   Next rng
End Sub
```

I got this idea from http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/find-cells-containing-formulas-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using the same example posted. BGeorge's looks correct as well.

```
Public Sub hightlightNoFormulas()
    Dim yourRange As Range
    Dim rangeNoFormula As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set yourRange = Range("A1:A100")
    Set rangeNoFormula = yourRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

    For Each rng In yourRange
        If Intersect(rng, rangeNoFormula) Is Nothing Then rng.Interior.Color = 65535
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, BGeorge's version worked as intended.